# How to check if an object is type of Class c?

Tags: java

I'm trying to do the following but it won't compile and keep saying "bo instanceOf T" is incompatibility

```
public retur boolean (BaseObject bo,String text, Class<?> T){
    return (bo.getText().equals(text) && bo instanceOf T)

}
```

I'm trying to ensure the get is the same and bo must be type of T.

oh yes how do I make sure the "T" extends BaseObject?

Comment: If `T` extends a `BaseObject` then the `BaseObject` can't be an instance of `T`.

Comment: Don't post two questions into one. Edit out the second question into a separate post.

Comment: @Tharwen Unless `T` is `BaseObject`. (If you go by the meaning of "extends" that Java's generic constraints use, that is "is assignable to".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
T.isAssignableFrom(bo.getClass());
```

See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) for details.

Comment: The type MUST be the same. I'm worried if bo is a child of Class<?> T, it will return true.. Should I use T.instanceOf(bo.getClass()); instead?

Comment: Then compare the classes: `bo.getClass() == T`. But this isn't the same thing as `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean test(BaseObject bo,String text, Class<? extends BaseObject> clazz){
   return ( bo.getText().equals(text) && clazz.isAssignableFrom(bo.getClass()) );
}
```